# Why is $\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right) \geq \frac{8}{xyz}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

The solution of a question in my book uses the property that 
$$\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right) \geq \frac{8}{xyz}$$ Where did they get it from? Is this using $AM >= GM >= HM$? In that case of what is the arithmetic/geometric/harmonic mean? Or is this some random mathematical property?

Comment: What are you assuming about $x$; $y$, and $z$?

Comment: I presume all of the variables are positive, in which case it's just AM/GM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if your variables assumed to be positive, you can use that
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{xy}}$$ for each factor.

Answer (score 4):

It comes indeed from the AM-GM inequality. If we assume that $x, y, z > 0$, then
$$
\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{yz}}
$$
and similarly for the other pairs. Multiplying these three equations gives the desired inequality.